# After Hosting Says ' HTTP Error 403.0 - ModSecurity Action You do not have permission to view this directory or page.'

Tags: angular, firewall, plesk, web-application-firewall

Angular Production Build and C# back end publish successfully completed. 
both dist and publish folder are uploaded to the Plesk server.

After that, it shows the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9fun.jpg)

when the web application firewall is turned off, it will work fine! so what's the issue?